# Changing WordPress URL results in 404

Tags: wordpress

Changing WordPress URL results in 404. I've tried basic suggestions like editing config.php myself or allowing rewrite.

First time changing URL worked, but page had text only- no theme, just plain text without formatting. I don't know what to do.

Comment: what changes you have done on `config.php` file?? and where is that `config.php` in wordpress?

Comment: I've added this in wp-admin/config.php: define('WP_HOME','http://www.ebooksalesinternational.com/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.ebooksalesinternational.com/wordpress'); I use hostgator and wordpress is in folder public_html. I really need  to get rid of that /wordpress in my url. 1 more thing- I haven't changed or touched nameserver in any options because I don't know how to do it and default url loads up fine. however 1 person suggested to start here.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your given url, you don't have any data yet into your site. Better option is, reinstall WordPress on the root directory instead of wordpress directory.

OR

Might be its working for you, Login into your website. Navigate the Settings > General

You will find two options:

```
WordPress Address (URL) :  http://www.ebooksalesinternational.com/wordpress
Site Address (URL) : http://www.ebooksalesinternational.com/wordpress
```

Set them to

```
WordPress Address (URL) :  http://www.ebooksalesinternational.com
Site Address (URL) : http://www.ebooksalesinternational.com
```

Comment: Changing URL through wordpress settings gave error that index file has problem in line 21. I needed to login through filezilla to fix it. Installing to root would be a simple sollution (the one experts provide) I like it. Let me go back a bit- when I started using cpanel, I installed wordpress through the cpanel interface but wasn't able to use it. Then I decided to use manual installation and thats where problems continued- changing url, trustjacker plugin workds like crap, and on top of that my webpage isn't displayed. http://www.ebooksalesinternational.com/wordpress/

Comment: I copied wordpress to root of hostgator. when I enter following url:ftp://ns6613.hostgator.com/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php I get only html code in browser. If I install wordpress into public_html folder, I can install wordpress but I can't change url and as you mentioned its not even on the "web".

Comment: @user47449 i can't understand hows you trying to install, after coping you don't have to enter the url like you mention, you simply have to enter your domain name, it will redirect you to install process

Comment: I copy thourh filezilla, then right-click on file and copy url. when I enter it domain./install hostgator says page not found.